# How to replace single occurances with the previous status

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a data table like below :

```
table=data.table(x=c(1:15),y=c(1,1,1,3,1,1,2,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3),z=c(1:15)*3)
```

I have to clean this data table where there are **single** occurrences like a 3 in between the 1s and a 1 in between the 2s. It doesn't have to be a 3 but any number which occurs only once should be replaced by the previous number.

```
table=data.table(x=c(1:15),y=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3),z=c(1:15)*3)
```

This is the expected data table.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The logic is unclear. Do you want to remove all occurrences of 3 in the `y` column if it is surrounded by other digits? What do the `x` and `z` columns have to do with the problem?

Comment: Not remove 3  but replace single occurence of all digits by the previous ones .x and z are just other data and nothing to do with y column but needed an approach for the whole data.table

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way :

```
library(data.table)
#Count number of rows for each group
table[, N := .N, rleid(y)]
#Change `y` value which have only one row
table[, y := replace(y, N ==1, NA)]
#Replace NA with last non-NA value
table[, y := zoo::na.locf(y)][, N := NULL]

table
#     x y  z
# 1:  1 1  3
# 2:  2 1  6
# 3:  3 1  9
# 4:  4 1 12
# 5:  5 1 15
# 6:  6 1 18
# 7:  7 2 21
# 8:  8 2 24
# 9:  9 2 27
#10: 10 2 30
#11: 11 3 33
#12: 12 3 36
#13: 13 3 39
#14: 14 3 42
#15: 15 3 45
```

Comment: This one doen't replace the 1 in the middle of 2 's sequence I guess

Comment: @Ricky It seems you changed the data after I posted the answer but this replaces all the single occurrences of digits. For your updated data row 7 has single occurrence of 2 which is changed by the previous occurrence i.e 1. Now this 1 is used to change the value at row 8 which is 1 again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option

```
inds <- which(diff(c(head(table$y,1),table$y))*diff(c(table$y,tail(table$y,1)))<0)
table$y <- replace(table$y,inds,table$y[inds-1])
```

such that

```
> table
     x y  z
 1:  1 1  3
 2:  2 1  6
 3:  3 1  9
 4:  4 1 12
 5:  5 1 15
 6:  6 1 18
 7:  7 2 21
 8:  8 2 24
 9:  9 2 27
10: 10 2 30
11: 11 3 33
12: 12 3 36
13: 13 3 39
14: 14 3 42
15: 15 3 45
```